# What is the 'smaller' side of an angle called?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Every angle has two sides, a big one and a small one. For example, a 90 degree angle also has a 270 degree angle on the other side. Is there a technical name within mathematics for the big and small sides of an angle? Thanks!

Comment: Supplementary...

Comment: You can maybe use the words "minor angle" and "major angle"

Comment: @FareedAF thanks that appears to be exactly what I'm looking for! Like minor and major arc. Cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two angles that sum to $360^\circ$ are known as [*explementary or conjugate angles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Combining_angle_pairs).

As one of them is always greater than $180^\circ$ (assuming the two angles are different), the larger one is known as a *reflex angle*. However, I don't think there is a generic term for the smaller angle of the two.

Comment: +1. I've never heard the term "explementary" before, but it apparently dates back to 1827 (according to [The Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words in Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/e.html)). Then again, I only became aware of "reflex angle" from people using it here on Math.SE, although [it dates back to 1876](http://jeff560.tripod.com/r.html). (I'm not sure how I missed these terms in my geometrical up-bringing.)

Comment: @Blue That is a very interesting site, thanks for linking it